# Providing multiple health check URLs for kubernetes probes

Tags: kubernetes, probe, kubernetes-health-check

I am using **container Probes** to check the health of the application running inside the container within kubernetes pod. For now my example pod config looks like,

```
"spec":{
   "containers":[
      {
        "image":"tomcat",
        "name":"tomcat",
        "livenessProbe":{
           "httpGet":{
              "port": 80
            },
            "initialDelaySeconds": 15,
            "periodSeconds": 10
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

In my case, I need to monitor two ports for the same container. **80** and **443**. But I am unable to find a method to provide both the ports for same container in the config file. Is there an alternate way of doing this?

Comment: I tried HEALTHCHECK docker command while creating the docker image. But even if the container is unhealthy, pod description doesn't give those details. I just states that the container is in running phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have curl / wget on the container you could just run a container exec healthcheck, and do something like `curl localhost:80 && curl localhost:443`.

Comment: This is what it looks like: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/pods/probe/exec-liveness.yaml

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, try to encapsulate the health check inside your application

Ex: 
http://localhost:80/health_check?full => (proxy to) => http://localhost:443/health_check?full

can be help you https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37218

Comment: I cannot touch my application. Need to do it from the outer level. I am looking for some other solution.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a very useful feature but that is missing.
As others mentioned earlier you can use a script for health check instead of httpget and check both urls in that script. 
One another option is to create a sidecar health container to monitor both urls of the main container and take action.